# How to call a custom attribute from a custom environment in openai gym?

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have a custom gym environment that works correctly when training a reinforcement learning model. However, if I create a custom attribute in the environment, I can't seem to call it in a different script.

```
# custom_env.py
...
class CustomEnv(gym.Env):
    """A custom environment for OpenAI gym"""

    def __init__(self, df, **kwargs):
        ...

    def reset(self):
        self.custom_attr = {"metric1":0, "metric2":0}
        return self._next_observation()
...
```

Above, `custom_attr` is a dict that records metrics for each iteration through the environment.

Then, in a separate script:

```
# train_rl.py
import CustomEnv
# ...
# training code here
# ...
metric_list = []
my_attr_dict = test_env.get_attr("custom_attr")
metric_list.append(my_attr["metric1"])  # error occurs here
```

I know that to return a user defined attribute from a gym environment, you have to use the [`get_attr`](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html#stable_baselines.common.vec_env.DummyVecEnv.get_attr) method, which is what I am trying to do in my `train_rl.py` script. But I get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when I try to append `my_attr["metric1"]` to `metric_list`. This indicates that `test_env.get_attr("custom_attr")` returns a list instead of a dict.

I'm wondering if I need to use the [`set_attr`](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html#stable_baselines.common.vec_env.DummyVecEnv.set_attr%60) at some stage in one of the scripts?

Comment: Are you using a vectorized environment? Did you look at what `test_env.get_attr("custom_attr")` returned? If you are using a vectorized environment, my (educated) guess is that it returns a list of dictionaries with the `len` of that list corresponding to the number of environment copies in the vector.